# Java default compilation directory

Tags: java, java-compiler-api

I'm using the Java Compiler API to build a couple of classes at runtime. However, I'd like these classes to be compiled into the default compilation directory, to where other class files are generated.

Is there a simple way to this? If I check the classpath I can see that the first URI is in fact the directory I want, but is it always the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I think I found a way, using the following:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip105.html?page=2

However, if there is a better way, please answer.